# Access external CDNs from Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I thought you can access external CDNs, as of the Winter '17 release, with `<ltng:require>`

I'm trying to access from component:

```
<ltng:require scripts="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
```

Getting this error:

> Sorry to interrupt
>
> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error
>   during init [Action failed: ltng$require$controller$init [Failed to
>   execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Refused to connect to
>   'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css'
>   because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.]]

Comment: I see a reference here : https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/05/loading-external-js-css-libraries-lightning-components.html  that says they may allow white listing CDNs by org but nowhere do I see a reference when this feature will be released. Where did you read about external CDN being part of winter 17

Comment: hmm I read on the blog, not remember where.

Comment: are you the author of the link you provided,  his name as yours :)

Comment: I wish :P, I am another person with a different first name and same last name